# Can I limit my Perl 6 program to running under a particular implementation?

Tags: raku, rakudo

The [dd](https://docs.raku.org/programs/01-debugging#Dumper_function_dd) routine is a Rakudo-specific feature, but that's incidental to my question. Is there a way inside a program to check the implementation and bail out if it's not the right one? Do I have to do this on my own?

```
 die "Unsupported VM" unless $*VM ~~ m/^ 'moar' /;
```

Maybe we need something like Perl 5's [Devel::AssertOS](https://www.metacpan.org/module/Devel::AssertOS).

I'm not at all interested in creating implementation-specific programs, but I can imagine cases where one implementation has particular quirks and bugs that are incompatible with a program. Because, you know, that was Java for several years (remember the [MRJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_Runtime_for_Java)?).

Comment: In theory you wouldn't need this if you keep to the standard. Why would the standard provide this when not needed?

Comment: @Sylwester Exactly which standard are you referring to?

Comment: @SinanÜnür In Perl5, if the documentation differs from the official implementation then the documentation needs fixing. you need to read perl5's source code for a spec. For perl6 there is a spec. Perl 6 is anything that passes the official test suite. And thus if this does not do `dd` then `dd` is not part of the language. Using `dd` will invalidate your program to be something else than perl6. You can call it a rakudo-program perhaps, but not perl6.

Comment: So, are there no Perl 6 implementations then?

Comment: @SinanÜnür True. None of the implementations today are complete. However my comment wasn't about that, but about using features not required by the standard in the first place. It's perhaps  nice for a implementation to make a superset of a language, but using the larger language locks the software to the implementation and won't run on any complete perl6 implementation in the future but the one that provided the non-perl6 feature. Scheme5 implementations are notorious for doing this and many have extra features with the same name but different contract/effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to run your program only on MoarVM, then:

```
BEGIN die "Must run on MoarVM, not $*VM.name()" unless $*VM.name eq 'moar';
```

should be enough.

UPDATE: added `BEGIN` as suggested by Jonathan Worthington

Comment: And stick a `BEGIN` before it to get it detected at compile time.

Comment: There's also [RakudoPrereq](http://modules.perl6.org/dist/RakudoPrereq) module one can use to lock down to a particular version of rakudo compiler.